# MySQL save result of INSERT INTO in a variable into a procedure?

Tags: mysql, procedure

This is my procedure, I need to do two INSERT, one of the values in the second INSERT is result the previous INSERT is this possible?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE crearEquipo(id_user INT, nombre VARCHAR(45))
COMMENT 'Procedimiento que guarda un equipo con un determinado nombre si no existe ese nombre para ese usuario'
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT ut.idTeam FROM usersTeam ut
    INNER JOIN teams t ON t.team_id = ut.team_id
    WHERE t.name = nombre AND ut.idUser = id_user
) 
THEN
    SET @id_team := (INSERT INTO teams(name) VALUES ( nombre));
    INSERT INTO usersTeam (idUser,idTeam) VALUES (id_user,@id_team);
    SELECT 'Equipo guardado correctamente!!!!';
ELSE
    SELECT 'Este equipo para ese cliente ya existe en la base de datos, cambie el nombreteams!';
END IF;
```

Comment: "result the previous INSERT" - The only result of an INSERT statement i can think of is `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: Thanks,that correct @PaulSpiegel

Answer (score 0):

To get the last id you must use the function LAST_INSERT_ID().
Para obtener el ultimo id debes usar la funcion LAST_INSERT_ID():

```
CREATE PROCEDURE crearEquipo(id_user INT, nombre VARCHAR(45))
COMMENT 'Procedimiento que guarda un equipo con un determinado nombre si no existe ese nombre para ese usuario'
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT ut.idTeam FROM usersTeam ut
    INNER JOIN teams t ON t.team_id = ut.team_id
    WHERE t.name = nombre AND ut.idUser = id_user
) 
THEN
     (INSERT INTO teams(name) VALUES ( nombre));
     SET @id_team :=LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO usersTeam (idUser,idTeam) VALUES (id_user,@id_team);
    SELECT 'Equipo guardado correctamente!!!!';
ELSE
    SELECT 'Este equipo para ese cliente ya existe en la base de datos, cambie el nombreteams!';
END IF;
```